# Login Error Phpvirtualbox

Tags: support, virtualbox

When trying to login in to phpvirtualbox, I get the message below:

```
Could not connect to host (http://127.0.0.1:18083/)
```

When I click on "details", I see:

```
Exception Object
(
[message:protected] => Could not connect to host (http://127.0.0.1:18083/)
[string:Exception:private] => 
[code:protected] => 64
[file:protected] => /var/www/html/phpvirtualbox/endpoints/api.php
[line:protected] => 134
[trace:Exception:private] => Array
(
)

[previous:Exception:private] => 
)
```

My server is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Xenial. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Add the user that runs the virtualmachines, your login account for example, to the vboxusers group:

```
sudo usermod -aG vboxusers USERACCOUNT
```

Then make sure to give the right ownership to the www dir:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:vboxusers /var/www/html/phpvirtualbox
```

Please note that if you have different locations you'd have to change it.

If that doesnt work please post the outcome of the following command:

```
ls -la /var/www/html
```

Comment: Instead of `sudo usermod -aG vboxusers USERACCOUNT`, the simpler alternative would be `sudo adduser USERACCOUNT vboxusers`.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
But in this case decided by changing two files and reinciciando the vboxweb service and daemon:

/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/vboxweb-service.service

/lib/systemd/system/vboxweb-service.service

I pulled the files of another 16:04 server that already ran the phpvirtualbox

Answer (score 0):

Check whether port 18083 is open (not closed).

```
*nmap localhost -p 18083*
```

Check settings in `/etc/default/virtualbox`

```
VBOXWEB_USER=vbox
VBOXWEB_PASSWD=????
VBOXWEB_TIMEOUT=0
VBOXWEB_LOGFILE=/var/log/vboxwebservice.log
VBOXWEB_HOST=127.0.0.1
```

Restart vboxsebsrv.

Check the logfile.